# How to transpose rows into single column based on time-stamp index in python?

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

Sample input dataset is:

[image]

Sample output dataset what i want:

```
0   2017-11-17 10:23:28.691 788
0   2017-11-17 10:23:28.691 756
0   2017-11-17 10:23:28.691 789
0   2017-11-17 10:23:28.691 780
1   2017-11-17 10:23:29.731 788
1   2017-11-17 10:23:29.731 783
2   2017-11-17 10:23:30.655 747
3   2017-11-17 10:23:31.627 766
4   2017-11-17 10:23:32.606 807
```

How can I do this by pandas? or is there any other technique to do this?

Comment: This is probably best suited for StackOverflow I think? It's a purely programming question.

Comment: I think this is fine. It's a data wrangling question.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I posted to Stackoverflow and got the answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437966/how-to-transpose-rows-into-single-column-based-on-time-stamp-index-in-python/47438169#47438169

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the following source DF:

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]:
         Time  val1  val2  val3
0  2017-11-17    11    12    13
1  2017-11-18    24    25     0
2  2017-11-19    37     0     0
```

Solution:

```
In [22]: (df.replace(0, np.nan)
            .set_index('Time', append=True)
            .stack()
            .reset_index()
            .rename(columns={0:'val'})
            .drop('level_2',1))
Out[22]:
   level_0        Time   val
0        0  2017-11-17  11.0
1        0  2017-11-17  12.0
2        0  2017-11-17  13.0
3        1  2017-11-18  24.0
4        1  2017-11-18  25.0
5        2  2017-11-19  37.0
```